# Camera intent with image only option

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to add camera intent to my app, I would like to give the user only option to take pictures (Not video), is there a way to hide the video button from the camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

only disables the button but its still being shown,
Thanks!

Comment: be aware that even if this option exists in *some* camera apps, there are different default camera apps in different firmwares, and also a lot of 3rd-party camera apps.

Comment: you can't do that. *dafault camera* may have different package name on different devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread over ~20,000 device models. Your `Intent` will open one of hundreds of possible camera apps, both pre-installed ones and ones that the user installs.

There is no option with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to request that certain camera capabilities be disabled for the user. Even if there was an option, there is no requirement for a camera app to honor it.

If you need that level of control over the camera, do not link to a camera app, but instead put camera capabilities directly in your app, either via the camera APIs (hard) or by using a library (CameraKit-Android, Fotoapparat, etc.).

Comment: which of the libraries do you recomend?

Comment: @Coder123: I haven't used one recently, so I'm not really in position to make a recommendation.